# Upload files to firebase storage via function

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage

I am trying to allow ability for user to select file and pass to firebase function to store in storage.

I am uploading file in react client like following:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("myFile", aFile);
const aRequesObject= {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData,
};
const response = await fetch(aUrl, aRequesObject);
```

Then I have a serverless function like following where i want to save this file to cloud storage.

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/storage";
import { config } from "./Config";
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const file = request.body.myFile;
const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(file.name);
ref.put(file).then(() => {
    console.log("Uploaded file", file.name);
  }); */
```

I have tried several variations from firebase documentation. All the examples i have found are uploading directly to storage from client as opposed to passing file to function and extracting from the request and then saving to storage. I am looking for a simple example of this or a link to where someone has done this scenario.